# VBA Customize collection object

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to learn how to create customized collections in Excel VBA and I found this piece of code on MSDN. While I understand most of it, can anyone tell me what the last code `Set Add = empNew` is doing? I don't understand it's comment. Thank you!

```
' Methods of the Employees collection class.
Public Function Add(ByVal Name As String, _
ByVal Salary As Double) As Employee
   Dim empNew As New Employee
   Static intEmpNum As Integer
   ' Using With makes your code faster and more
   ' concise (.ID vs. empNew.ID).
   With empNew
      ' Generate a unique ID for the new employee.
      intEmpNum = intEmpNum + 1
      .ID = "E" & Format$(intEmpNum, "00000")
      .Name = Name
      .Salary = Salary
      ' Add the Employee object reference to the
      ' collection, using the ID property as the key.
      mcolEmployees.Add empNew, .ID
   End With
   ' Return a reference to the new Employee.
   Set Add = empNew
End Function
```

Comment: When you call `Add()` method, this line just returns created `empNew` instanse as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will notice that `Add` is the name of the `Function`. By issuing `Set Add = newEmp` your code is declaring that the [return value](http://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-sub/#Function_How_to_Return_Values) (or object, in this case) of the function, is the newly created employee object `newEmp`. This means that the function will pass the variable `newEmp` back to its caller.

Say that you had some procedure calling your function, you would be able to do this:

```
Sub listEmployees
    Dim e As Employee

    ' Create a new employee, and assign the variable e to point to this object
    Set e = Add("John", 1000) ' Notice that the only reason we use "add" here is because it is the name of the function you provided

    ' e is now an Employee object, after being created in the line above, meaning we can access whatever properties is defined for it. The function Add lists some properties, so we can use those as examples.
    Debug.Print e.Name
    Debug.Print e.Salary
    Debug.Print e.ID
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! So this means I can change this function to a sub if I don't need it to return any value (or object) right? I think I understand it now.

Comment: That is correct - the difference is indeed that a `Sub` doesn't return anything, it's basically just a program that runs, while a `Function` returns something to whatever it was invoked by.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to define the new `Type` you have created, so put the following code on top of your module:

```
Public Type Employee
    id As String
    Name As String
    Salary As Long
End Type
```

Then, inside your `Public Function Add` , change to `Dim empNew As Employee`.
Not sure why you need the following line : `mcolEmployees.Add empNew, .id` ??

and the last line modify to `Add = empNew`.

Then, when I test this Function from the following Sub:

```
Sub testEmp()

Dim s As Employee

s = Add("Shai", 50000)

End Sub
```

I get for `s` in the immediate window the following values:

```
s.id = E00001
s.Name = "Shai"
s.Salary = 50000
```

I hope this is what you intended in your post.

Comment: Thank you! This is not my code & not complete so it might be a little confusing. I understand it now.

Comment: @yatsky if I helped you solve the question in your post, then mark as "ANSWER"

Comment: I think Vegard's answer is more like what I was chasing for but thank you for your help.